# AVAudioRecorder & debugger stops with no signal

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios-simulator, avaudiorecorder

I need to record audio stream with iPhone mic.
I am using AVAudioRecorder from this thing.

I initialize AVAR in init:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cachePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] retain];
NSError *error;
BOOL isDir = NO;
if (! [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:cachePath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir == NO) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:cachePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
}

pathNewFile=  [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"123.caf"];

NSLog(@"%@",pathNewFile);

NSDictionary *settings=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0f],AVSampleRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleLossless],AVFormatIDKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMax],AVEncoderAudioQualityKey, nil];
recorder=[[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pathNewFile] settings:settings error:nil];
[recorder prepareToRecord];
```

And I start recording when user presses the rec-button:

```
-(void)recButton:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"start rec");
        [rootNotesButton setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [rootNotesButton removeTarget:self action:@selector(recButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [rootNotesButton addTarget:self action:@selector(stopButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [recorder record];
}

-(void)stopButton:(id)sender{
            NSLog(@"stop rec");
            [rootNotesButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [rootNotesButton removeTarget:self action:@selector(stopButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [rootNotesButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [recorder stop];
}

-(void)playButton:(id)sender{
        NSLog(@"play rec");
            [rootNotesButton setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [rootNotesButton removeTarget:self action:@selector(playButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [rootNotesButton addTarget:self action:@selector(stopPButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pathNewFile] error:nil];
            [player play];
}

-(void)stopPButton:(id)sender{
        NSLog(@"Stop play");
            [rootNotesButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [rootNotesButton removeTarget:self action:@selector(stopPButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [rootNotesButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [player stop];
}
```

But when I try to run my project in simulator: My debugger stops on string: 
recorder=[[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pathNewFile] settings:settings error:nil]; Without any signal or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with writing to `cachePath` in the Simulator. I tried this and it worked:

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    NSString *cachePath = @"/tmp";
#else
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cachePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] retain];
#endif
```

You have a couple memory leaks:

1. You are retaining `cachePath` but not releasing it. There's actually no reason to retain it in the first place.
2. You are creating `player` with `+alloc/-init` in `playButton` which means you own it but you are not releasing it (at least not in the posted code). If you are defining it as a `property` you need to use `self.player = …` in order for it to be properly retained and released.
3. You are creating `settings` with `+alloc/-init` but not releasing it. There's no reason to do that. You can create it like this instead:

`NSDictionary *settings=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0f],AVSampleRateKey,
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleLossless],AVFormatIDKey,
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMax],AVEncoderAudioQualityKey, nil];`

You need to retain `pathNewFile` because `stringByAppendingPathComponent` returns an autoreleased string and you are using it in other methods of your class.

Comment: Thank you. It works.
Yes i know that. It is just test variant my program. And i write it from test method of audio recording. In final relies i fixed all bug and error.  
Thanks for advice.